# Slack API: how do I tell if a message is coming from a single user private channel to my Slackbot?

Tags: slack-api

How can I detect if a message is from a user who is chatting with my bot in a private channel (DM with only the bot) using the Event API?

Comment: Your question is too general. Please provide some specifics about how your slackbot is setup, e.g. are you using the RTM API or the Event API for your bot? What information are you currently getting from the user when he sends a DM message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the first letter in the channel id.  If it starts with `D` it is a DM channel. If it starts with `C` it is a public channel.

For example, `D2AH456` is a DM channel, whereas `C234F56` is a public #channel

Comment: Gonna add from another post which I now can't find. `G` is for private or group channels